# Why is the Hamiltonian operator an infinite dimensional matrix? How can we write the Hamiltonian operator as a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, physics

One of my teachers said that the [Hamiltonian operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)) can be thought of as infinite dimensional matrix, but I could not understand *why*. Moreover, if that is true, then how can we write the Hamiltonian operator as a matrix?

P.S: Please don't use concepts much beyond high school level. I know the basics of matrices and am still in the process of learning linear algebra topics like "Vector spaces". So try to explain in simple words as much as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Because it's a linear operator on an infinite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: @Arthur What does that mean? :/

Comment: I might say "linear map" or "linear function" instead, but if that isn't enough to help you, then I suggest you try to look at this again in a month when you understand more about the connections between vector spaces, matrices, bases and linear maps. There are so many small, interconnecting facts that you need to understand that a single post here can hardly cover it.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how a derivative can  be approximated in a finite space, you know the answer to your question.

Any derivative of a continuous function $f$, let it be for example $f''$ can be approximated using Taylor series for a discrete space:
$$f''\approx \frac{f_{i+1}-2 f_{i}+  f_{i-1}}{h^2}$$
This equation permits a representation in matrix form:
$$f'' \approx D^2f$$

Where $D^2$ is proportional to the following matrix:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & -1 & ...& &\\
-1 & 2 &- 1 &...&\\
0 & -1 & 2 &- 1 &...\\
... &&&&\\\
... &&-1&2&-1\\
...\\ &&&-1&2
\end{matrix}\right]$$
Therefore if $h\to 0$ then the finite dimensional space turns into an infinite dimensional one, lesding to a infinite matrix $D^2$ representind the second derivative in continuum.

Comment: What does $f_{i-1}$ and $f_{i+1}$ stand for?

Comment: The values of the function $f$ evaluated in the discrete points $x_i$

Comment: Ok. But why did you write $f_{i+1}$ and $-2f_{i+1}$ separately in the expression for $f'$? Also, can you state the source of that equation?

Comment: Sorry my fault. I am writing with my phone. It is now corrected. Put in google central finite difference scheme for second derivative to do some research about that equation.